# Using ReturnType of a method of an abstract class in a Child class

Tags: typescript, generics, return-type

I'm trying to use the ReturnType of a method of an abstract class in a child class.
But typescript raises lot of error

below is a very basic example, but easy to understand the issue.

Thks

```
abstract class Parent<A>{
    private _value:A
    constructor (value:A){
        this._value=value
    }

    protected getValue():A {
        return this._value
    }

}

class ChildString extends Parent<string>{
    constructor(value:string){
        super(value)
    }

    public stringValue():ReturnType<typeof this.getValue> { //<---- error is here
        return this.getValue()
    }

}
```

the error is similar to

> Return type of public method from exported class has or is using private 'this'

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid using `this` by direct use of class method

```
ReturnType<ChildString['getValue']>
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgCsKBTAdhADwCCAfAN4BQCtCADlAJYBuwEuCA+m8gK64AXCRp1YAe3yQofeOKgIAFLwHCAlNTpaEEABZMwAOh7B+uALwrco2gF8qNhlHEd4uACYIA5rggA1UwFFNWEETW1aPAg+KHwdfSMTM0d7eyoUNAwAYX1kdwBlaCZ8LwRcAA8OfHcMbDxCImlir0pHCSloWQh5ZUChJpKNRy0wPnpcKF6zNRTHej4QZCZYBAGvALNgwQAlXxj8ABUAT3GiHKY8wuYSgG0Ach9-PruAXTIw4boo-fiDQ0eNkEZlpUulJJAkBhzGFbAg0AhzpciiUANxgjoIFgIaGwIxrQG4YIIAD0xNWyK8QA)

Comment: brilliant! thks